# Выбрать людей по возрастным группам, используя COUNT и HAVING

Tags: sql

Всем привет,

Есть таблица ppl, которая содержит

```
id
name
age
```

Мне нужно найти количество людей с одинаковым возрастом и вывести их, но с условием, что в данной возрастной грруппе должно быть больше 10 человек. Колонки для вывода:

```
age
total_people
```

Вот мой запрос, но он не проходит:

```
SELECT age, COUNT(*) as total_people
FROM people
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
GROUP BY age
```

Comment: Попробуйте `HAVING` поставить после `GROUP BY`, по-моему так правильно должно быть.

Comment: У меня была неправильная структура запроса. GROUP BY должен идти перед HAVING. Следующий запрос работает корректно:
    SELECT age, COUNT(*) as total_people
    FROM people
    GROUP BY age
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10

Answer (score 3):

Правильный ответ:

```
SELECT age, COUNT(*) as total_people
FROM people
GROUP BY age
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
```